# Unsuccessful Login

Tags: php, authentication

I have tried login and it didn't work, when I login, it just stay at the blank page. No errors has shown.

I have made a form in index.php. If the user hasn't logout, the name of user will output on the page. And if the user hasn't login, it will show a login form. The following code below:

```
<div class="topRight">
        <?php
            ini_set('display_errors',1); 
            error_reporting(E_ALL);
            include "config/dbconnect.php";

            if(isset($_SESSION['login'])&&!empty($_SESSION['login'])) {            
                $name = $_SESSION['user_info']['name'];
                echo '<p> <a href="profileUser"> Profile : $name </a>';
                } else {
                echo    '<form action="actions/login.php" method="POST">
                            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email">
                            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                            <input type="submit" value="LOGIN">
                        </form>';
                echo    '<p> <a href="registerForm.php" class="underline"> Not a member? Register here! </a> </p>
                        <p> <a href="actions/logout.php"> Logout </a> </p>';
            }
        ?>
    </div>
```

After login, it will directly to login.php as shown as below:

```
<?php
  ob_start(); 
  session_start();
  ini_set('display_errors', 1);
  error_reporting(-1);
?>

<?php
include "../config/dbconnect.php";

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $username = trim($_POST['email']);
        $password = trim($_POST['password']);

        $username = $mysqli->real_escape_string($username);
        $password = $mysqli->real_escape_string($password);

        $salt = sha1(md5($password));
        $epwd = md5($password.$salt);

        $loginUser = "  SELECT * FROM memberTable
                        WHERE email = '$email' AND password = '$epwd'";

        $loginSuccess = mysqli_query($mysqli, $loginUser) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
        $loginRow = mysqli_num_rows($loginSuccess);

        if($loginRow === 1) {

            session_start();
            $_SESSION['login'] = true;

            $user_info = mysqli_fetch_assoc($loginSuccess);
            $_SESSION['user_info'] = $user_info; // put user_info to call all details for later use

            header ("Location: ../index.php");
            } else {
                header ("Location: ../header.php");
            }

    mysqli_close($mysqli);
    }
?>
```

The following code for dbconnect.php is below:

```
<?php
    //Open a new connection to the MySQL server
    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','root','root','database_name');

    //Output any connection error
    if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
        die('Error : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
    }
?>
```

The result is when I sign in with a form, it successfully navigate to login.php. But it just stopped there with a blank page and not redirecting to index.php. There are no error has shown.

What I have done is:

1. I simply put `ini_set('display_errors',1);` and it still not showing any errors.
2. I have checked dbconnect.php, and the connections between index.php and login.php to dbconnect.php is linking very well.

Still it didn't show any sign like this [screenshot](http://prntscr.com/5qn7cp). Am I missing something?

Comment: Do you have a `session_start();` in the first code box? Otherwise you missed that

Comment: @Rizier123 Oh yah! I missed this `session_start();`. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Did that solved the error?

Comment: @Rizier123 that's working for session only, not working for error :/

Comment: you use a var_dump($_SESSION);die(); for checking the session value in index.php

Comment: Hey @SathishS, before, im using session, login is not working. not successfully yet. :/

Answer (score 0):

header ("Location: ../index.php"); needs to be fallowed by an exit statement

```
header("Location: ../whatever.php");
exit;
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: I have tried this, and it doesn't work? @kayleighsdaddy

Answer (score 0):

you start a `session` at two places one is enough,then also you need to check the $user_info values set in $_SESSION['user_info'] `var_dump($_SESSION['user_info']);die();`

after that remove space from `header ();` like `header();`

now you tried what you have found in screen,

Comment: can you re modify that coding again? I don't where I can edit. haha.. quite confusing..

Comment: I just realised I put two places. I just removed one of them. And also you mean I have to replace `$_SESSION['user_info'] = $user_info;` into that one you mentioned?

Comment: you check the values set in $_SESSION['user_info'] using 'var_dump($_SESSION['user_info']);' in below the line of $_SESSION['user_info'] = $user_info; in login.php

Comment: I will use `var_dump`. But the problem is after I logged in, it just stopped at login.php with a blank page. I can't figure it out whats wrong with my code. I have put `ini_set('display_errors',1);` but it didn't show any errors. Just a blank page.

Answer (score 0):

whenever u use header() , we must sure that output must not started before. Results in blank line output.

```
?>

<?php
```

header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP
You have added some space between

```
<?php
  ob_start(); 
  session_start();
  ini_set('display_errors', 1);
  error_reporting(-1);
?>

<?php
include "../config/dbconnect.php";
```

Try to make like below and try again.

```
<?php
  ob_start(); 
  session_start();
  ini_set('display_errors', 1);
  error_reporting(-1);
  include "../config/dbconnect.php";
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
..........................
```

Comment: change the order of session_start and ob_start . Put session_start first and then ob_start. Put Exit after header().exit();