# Registering Successfully but not for Session to call username

Tags: php, html

I have made a simple form for registering. When I register, I have to put *email*, *password* and *fullname*. But once I registered, it successfully inserted into Database. But I wanted it to show the name of user on the top heeader. First of all, the following code below:

registerForm.php :

```
<form id="myForm" action="actions/register.php" method="POST">  
            <p> Email Address : </p>
            <p> <input name="email" required="required" type="text" placeholder="eg. john.wick@yahoo.com"/> </p>
            <p> Password : </p>
            <p> <input name="password" required="required" type="password" placeholder="Your password"/> </p>
            <p> Full Name : </p>
            <p> <input name="name" required="required" type="text" placeholder="Your full name"/> </p> 
    <p class="centre"> <input type="submit" value="REGISTER"> </p>
</form>
```

register.php :

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    include "../config/dbconnect.php";

        $name = ucwords(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
        $emailAddress = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);
        $registerPassword = $_POST['password'];

        $name = $mysqli->real_escape_string($name);
        $emailAddress = $mysqli->real_escape_string($emailAddress);
        $registerPassword = $mysqli->real_escape_string($registerPassword);


        $salt = sha1(md5($registerPassword));
        $hashedPW = md5($registerPassword.$salt);

        $check = "SELECT * FROM memberTable where email = '$emailAddress'";
        $checkTitle = mysqli_query($mysqli,$check) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));

        if (mysqli_num_rows($checkTitle) > 0) {
           header("location: ../header.php");
        } else {
            $insertSQL = "INSERT INTO memberTable (email, password, name) VALUES ('$emailAddress', '$hashedPW', '$name')";
            $queryResult = mysqli_query($mysqli,$insertSQL) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));

            if($queryResult) {
                $user_info = array(
                    'name' => $name,
                );

                $_SESSION['login'] = true;
                $_SESSION['user_info'] = $user_info;
            }

            header("location: ../index.php");
            exit;
        }

    mysqli_close($mysqli);
?>
```

When it's not successfully registered, it will show a login form. Whereas the registration is successful, it will directly to header.php. To know that I have inserted my fullname, email and password into database. I want my full name to show on the header. Something like this below:

```
<div class="topRight">
        <?php
            ini_set('display_errors',1); 
            include "config/dbconnect.php";

            if(isset($_SESSION['login']) && !empty($_SESSION['login'])) {            
                $name = $_SESSION['user_info']['name'];

                echo '<p> <a href="profileUser"> Profile : $name </a>';
                echo '<p> <a href="actions/logout.php"> Logout </a> </p>';

                } else {

                echo    '<form action="actions/login.php" method="POST">
                            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email">
                            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                            <input type="submit" value="LOGIN">
                        </form>';

                echo    '<p> <a href="registerForm.php" class="underline"> Not a member? Register here! </a> </p>';
            }
        ?>
    </div>
```

The problem is `Profile : $name` is not working. It didn't show the name but just `$name` on the webpage. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this.,

```
echo '<p> <a href="profileUser"> Profile :'.$name.'</a>';
```

you should keep to close quotation correctly,

Comment: Ahhh that's working for now. No wonder I miss that. Anyway, can you help me for login? it didn't show any errors, but you know when I login, there are no errors shown. And also I want to show the name after login successful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27853457/unsuccessful-logins-and-session-in-php

Comment: I wanted to accept this answer but need to wait for 5 mins :/

Answer (score 0):

Variables inside single quotes don't get parsed. [PHP Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single)

Comment: Ouch I miss that. Thanks for the hint. Btw can you help me for login? It's because login didn't work and also something for like register. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27853457/unsuccessful-logins-and-session-in-php